# DataColumn Dynamic in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-widget

Hi This Is My Table And Data Row is Daynamic How Can Change Data Column Dynamicly like row?

```
 DataTable2(
                columnSpacing: 12,
                horizontalMargin: 12,
                minWidth: 600,
                columns: [
            DataColumn(label: Text("1")),
            DataColumn(label: Text("2")),
            DataColumn(label: Text("3")),
            DataColumn(label: Text("4")),
            DataColumn(label: Text("5"))
          ],rows: listItem!.map<DataRow>((e) => DataRow(cells: [

            DataCell(Text('${e.itemInfo?.clientName}''${e.itemInfo?.clientFamilyName}')),
            DataCell(Text('${e.itemInfo!.company}')),
              DataCell(Text(e.itemInfo!.clientMobile.toString())),
            DataCell(Text('${e.itemInfo?.clientStoreCity}')),
              DataCell(Text('${e.itemInfo?.clientStoreAddress}')),

            ])).toList()),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume this is your data that you want to put in DataColumn:

```
var data = ["1","2","3","4","5",];
```

you can use this:

```
columns: data.map((e) => DataColumn(label: Text(e))).toList();
```

Comment: its not working and show null error page

Comment: can you update your question with my answer, and show me the error message?

Comment: thank your i do some changed in my code and use it your code ..it was ok..thank you for helping me for few times